# Why does the Czech government need EU permission to change the way vaccines are administered?

Tags: european-union, covid-19, czech-republic

According to the [Twitter of Andrej Babiš](https://twitter.com/AndrejBabis/status/1343653164357189633) (Czech prime minister):

> This evening I have asked the EC President @vonderleyen
> to explore and approve together with @EMA_News
> as soon as possible the possibility of using a Pfizer ampule for six doses instead of five. It would mean 360 million doses instead of 300 million doses of Pfizer vaccine for the EU. I strongly hope that the EC President will find a solution shortly.

But why is EU approval required in the first place? Couldn't the Czech government unilaterally mandate that all six doses are used instead of five? Is there anything in EU rules that precludes such experimentation?

Comment: "It would mean 360 million doses instead of 300 million doses of Pfizer vaccine for the EU" For the EU, not just Czechia. There's nothing in the tweet that indicates the Czech prime minister is asking for approval for how the Czech government will proceed with vaccinations.

Comment: This is not about experimentation.

Comment: This is irrelevant to your actual question but you seem to imply that the Pfizer vaccine contains 6 doses and according to EU regulations only 5 are used. The original tweet rather says that the vaccine is sold in ampules with a certain quantity of vaccine. EU regulations say this is enough for making 5 doses. The Czech prime minister suggest giving everyone 5/6 of a dose so that it covers more people, hoping that the smaller quantity is just as effective as the full dose. Whether this is a good idea should be jugded with medical expertise not by politicians.

Comment: @quarague What makes you think that? The follow-up tweets refer to a similar discussion in the US which was solely about using what's left in the vial after administering five full doses and certainly not about a different dosage. The dose is not defined based on what's in the vial, it's the other way around.

Comment: @Relaxed So you are saying admister 5 full doses and one left over dose? How is that any different? The left over dose will be significantly smaller than the full doses, whether they would still be useful is a medical question. Or do you assume Pfizer sells vaccine in say 3 milliliter ampules and then writes in the instruction please make 5 doses of 0.5 ml and then throw away the remaining 0.5 ml?

Comment: @quarague Sorry if I wasn't clear, I am indeed talking about an extra full dose or more that would otherwise be discarded. Personnally, it's not something I knew or assumed to be there before this issue came up but US healthcare providers  reportedly noticed that more than one full dose remained in the vial at the end (some sources suggest it might even be possible to get two). AFAIK, the FDA only allows using any remaining full doses but *not* administering smaller doses nor mixing different vials. That's the basis for the whole discussion.

Comment: @quarague Multidose vials are routinely filled with more than required for the intended number of doses, so that any slight spillage doesn't mean the last dose is too small. Apparently in this case the "extra" vaccine Pfizer has included in its vials is more than one full extra dose. See e.g. https://www.politico.com/news/2020/12/16/pfizer-vaccine-extra-doses-447117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, this vaccine is distributed under an EU-wide “Conditional Marketing Authorisation” based on a recommendation from the [European Medicines Agency](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en). This authorisation constrains what can be done with the vaccine, certainly as far as the manufacturer, marketing authorisation holder, and national governements are concerned (legally, individual practitioners might have some leeway in how they administer a medicine). Similar processes exist elsewhere.

Under existing European law, neither national governments nor even the EU Commission itself are supposed to circumvent this process and allow random compounds to be used as medicinal products or issue arbitrary recommendations for their use without consulting the agencies they set up to regulate this. From that perspective, unless it wants to issue another authorisation, the Czech government cannot unilaterally do anything.

EU law does however foresee other types of approvals for medicinal products that could be issued at the national level:

- Emergency Use Authorisation
- National/Mutual Recognition Procedure

Legally, the Czech Republic could issue an Emergency Use Authorisation for a Covid-19 vaccine without asking the EU for permission but all EU countries indicated earlier this year that they preferred [to follow the regular “Conditional Marketing Authorization” process](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/QANDA_20_2390). Consequently, I assume that no manufacturer applied for approval at the national level.

In many cases, manufacturers can also apply for approval through a National/Mutual Recognition Procedure but EU law restricts those. In particular, the centralised procedure is mandatory for products developed with certain techniques like recombinant DNA technology. If I understand the Pfizer/BioNTec vaccine correctly, this rule seems to preclude a national marketing authorisation for that particular product (but that will not necessarily be the case for all other vaccines).

In both cases, the approval would not be solely in the hands of the Czech cabinet but should be initiated by an application by the manufacturer and go through the National Competent Authority, namely the [State Institute for Drug Control](http://www.sukl.eu/). That, rather than EU harmonization, is what ties the hands of the Czech government.

Comment: Minor correction. *should be initiated by an application by the manufacturer and go through the National Competent Authority, namely the State Institute for Drug Control* => the Czech parliament (controlled by the Prime Minister, to a certain degree) could pass a special law that abolishes these requirements, if they wanted.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, not under existing EU law. Of course, the Czech Republic could also leave the EU, etc. etc. but that's not a very useful way to look at this. In other words: EU law did not fully harmonise the authorisation process nor does it require EU permission for each and every medicine but it does require each member state to have a standard process.

Comment: I seem to recall that there are differences in liabilities for emergency and conditional authoritzation. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: +1 but I think you're wrong about "reverse genetics" as applicable here. The EU [has](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6728416/) some specific rules which exclude vaccines (even those with DNA/RNA) from being categorized as recombinant products. "In EU, there is one exclusion criterion that explicitly vetoed a product from being classified as a gene therapy: those products aimed at the treatment or prophylaxis of infectious diseases."

Comment: "These products would be classified as vaccines, even if the product meets all of the necessary criteria to be considered an advanced therapy (European Medicines Agency, 2015).  For instance, a modified vaccinia virus ankara (MVA) into which two genes have been placed for the treatment of non-small cell lung cancer is classified as a GTMP, but if these genes lead to foreign protein expression for the treatment of human immunodeficiency virus (HIV) disease, the product will not be considered an advanced therapy, but a vaccine (European Medicines Agency, 2016b"

Comment: "The same principle applies to non-viral vectored products such as most plasmid DNA- or RNA-based products. For instance, Trimix is a mixture of mRNAs encoding for antigen presenting cell activation molecules. If this mixture of mRNAs is combined with tumor-associated antigens for the treatment of melanoma, the therapy is classified as a GTMP, but if these mRNA are combined with mRNA encoding for HIV antigens, the therapy will be considered a vaccine (European Medicines Agency, 2016b). "

Comment: @Fizz I might indeed be completely wrong about that but is this whole discussion about the same issue? Does that mean it's not subject to mandatory use of the centralized procedure?

Comment: I'm saying there probably aren't any EU rules stemming from how a drug (advanced or not) was discovered. That's what [reverse genetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_genetics) is actually about. The EU rules (almost certainly) are just down to what's in the final product and what's intended for.

Comment: @Fizz You're right about that, the rules are based on how a product is manufactured, not how it's discovered. The terminology used in regulation [726/2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02004R0726-20190330) is "recombinant DNA technology” but I came across the phrase “reverse genetics” in [this guideline on influenza vaccines](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/regulatory-procedural-guideline/guideline-influenza-vaccines-submission-procedural-requirements_en.pdf) from the EMA.

Comment: Trying to reconcile this with the article you found, I was wondering whether the  advanced therapy vs. vaccine classification was a different distinction than that implied by regulation 726/2004. In fact, I just noticed that annex I of the regulation includes a separate item (1a) for “Advanced therapy medicinal products”, which strongly suggests that item 1 specifically covers products manufactured by recombinant DNA technology which are *not* considered ATMP.

Answer (score 2):

The 300 million refers to the [number of doses procured from BioNTech and Pfizer by the European Union](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/ip_20_2081). As such, the requested increase to 360 million (which corresponds to going from five to six doses) appears to be an EU-wide increase.

One clear reason why the EU would be involved in such a request is that the vaccines were procured jointly through the EU. If more doses are needed per person, fewer people can be vaccinated by the existing order. The easiest option is to amend the order to buy more doses of the vaccine, which is what the Czech prime minister requests here.

---

> Couldn't the Czech government unilaterally mandate that all six doses are used instead of five? Is there anything in EU rules that precludes such experimentation?

That seems to be more of a regulatory question. I don't think that's an issue here as [member states are allowed to authorize medicines at the national level](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/about-us/what-we-do/authorisation-medicines):

> While the majority of new, innovative medicines are evaluated by EMA and authorised by the European Commission in order to be marketed in the EU, most generic medicines and medicines available without a prescription are assessed and authorised at national level in the EU.

Of course, the tweet does mention EMA exploration and approval, so there is some regulatory angle. Considering that the [EMA has been in charge](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/news/ema-recommends-first-covid-19-vaccine-authorisation-eu) of the vaccine's approval in the EU up to now, it makes sense for them to evaluate this change as well. Furthermore, approval by the EMA applies to the EU as a whole whereas national authorization would require a [mutual recognition procedure](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/glossary/mutual-recognition) to apply the change in other member states.

In that regard, the same reasons for centralizing procurement and authorization EU-wide any medicine apply to the vaccines for a disease which clearly affects all countries in the EU.